# How to define hidden properties on Angular $scope

Tags: angularjs

Consider:

```
$scope.taylor = {
    firstName: 'taylor',
    lastName: 'mcintyre',
    order: 22 
}
```

Using $resource, I might want to save this:

```
people.save($scope.taylor);
```

However, I do not want the property "order" to be sent along with the request.

Angular ignores properties prefixed with '$$' for it's own internal use, but it doesn't feel right prefixing my own hidden properties in this way, e.g.

```
$scope.taylor = {
    firstName: 'taylor',
    lastName: 'mcintyre',
    $$order: 22 
}
```

**Deleting** unwanted properties is the common-sense solution, but does Angular have a better solution for this?

Comment: Ehh...don't think so...you could always roll your own function where you define what properties to ignore via an array, then pass the return object of that function along to the service\

Comment: yes that's what I've done. This just seems like a recurring problem.

Comment: or, rather, it seems like a common problem

Comment: Why are you sending the scope with the request instead of an object stored in the scope?

Comment: I'm sending an object stored on the $scope, $scope.taylor. I am not sending $scope itself. Maybe I am misunderstanding you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you are looking for an "Angular way" to exclude keys, but [angular.copy()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) doesn't seem to support this. The [angular.toJson()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.toJson) documentation states: `Properties with leading $ characters will be stripped since angular uses this notation internally.` This sounds like using `$` should be reserved for angular and not used by us in our objects.

In light of the situation I created a [simple CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KCtdr) showing how easily this can be done using a library like [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/).

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this, but my example does accomplish what I understood to be your primary goal.

I included the UnderscoreJS library in my file and added the following code:

```
var person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Smith',
  order: 22,
  excludeKeys: [
    'order',
    'excludeKeys'
  ]
};

var personCopy = _.omit(person, person.excludeKeys);

console.log('person: ', person);
console.log('person copy: ', personCopy);
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Starting with angularjs 1.3.0, only properties leading $$ characters will be stipped.